# Is there a way to reduce the delay in sending nodemailer emails using yahoo smtp?

Tags: javascript, next.js, smtp, vercel, nodemailer

I have a contact form that sends an email when hitting the submit button. When the email is sent, there is a delay of about 2 minutes before it lands up in the inbox. Is there a way to improve upon this delay?

The SMTP host I am using is `smtp.mail.yahoo.com` and the mailing service is nodemailer.

My project is hosted in Vercel. The email lands in the inbox almost instantaneously when I am debugging in my local environment, but I experience the delay when its deployed to production.

My transporter setting is as follows:

```js
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    port: 465,
    host: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_HOST,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_PASS,
    },
    secure: true,
  });
```

I used nodemailer, Yahoo smtp host and everything is deployed in Vercel. In my local environment, the email lands almost instantly in the inbox, but when its deployed to production (Vercel), the delay is about 2 minutes.

Comment: Examine the `Received:` headers in the email to see where the delay is occurring.

Comment: @Barmar thank you. That narrowed down the issue to `sonic.gate.mail.ne1.yahoo.com` where its taking 2 minutes. Weirdly this same hop is taking 6 seconds when I send the mail through my localhost so I am still kind of confused where to go from here other than "use another smtp service".

Comment: There might be some spam filtering going on.

Comment: @Barmar the email does not land up in the spam folder. But are you suggesting its taking time because of the very process of yahoo trying to decide if the email is spam? Is there any recommendation to improve upon this? Its weird because I sent almost identical messages and settings using my local host where it took just a few seconds

Comment: You can bypass yahoo mail altogether and use direct SMTP, although it can be tricky avoiding your own mail been tagged spam, but with properly setup DNS records it's certainly possible.

Comment: I didn't mean that it's being blocked as spam, just that the software that checks for spam holds it for 2 minutes.

Comment: @Barmar
So recently the email no longer has the delays. I think yahoo finally whitelisted my address.